# Yii CListView Pagination - beforeAjaxUpdate detect if is prev or next

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm creating a CListView in Yii with an animation triggered by beforeAjaxUpdate (and of course another triggere by afterAjaxUpdate).

It is all working pretty good but I'm wondering how to pass the direction of the navigotion to my javascript function. 
I mean, if I click "Next" I would like to pass a variable like:

```
"direction = forward"
```

to my function, else if I click "Previous" I like the variable to be:

```
"direction = reverse".
```

The end point is to customize the direction of the animation.

Any suggestion on how to pass this variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of the page on which the user moves from URL AJAX request as follows:

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id, options){
    var reg = /page[\/|=](\d+)/ig;
    var pageArray = reg.exec(options.url);
    var page = pageArray? pageArray[1] : 1;
    console.log(page);
}
```

But you should save the current page number to compare with this value. Comparing these values ​​can be found direction.